Newcomb's paradox with truly random (e.g., quantum) choice
Suppose we decide to choose either one box or two box in Newcomb's problem randomly. For example, we can measure a qubit in the |0> + |1> state in the {|0>, |1>} basis; if we measure |0> then we choose one box and if we measure |1> we choose two boxes. We can also stipulate that the predictor's handling of the boxes is spacelike separated from the quantum measurement, so that no signal travels between them.
If the predictor has to correctly guess the choice then he'll need to accurately predict the result of a quantum measurement. So he'll need to have access to a nonlocal hidden variable theory or superdeterminism.
Does this rule out the existence of a predictor that doesn't have access to that?

The predicting in Newcomb's setup is not the reason for the paradox and is not limited by physics. It can be by divine revelation or clairvoyance, for all it matters. There are also mundane variants where no superpowers are needed at all, see SEP:"The essential feature of Newcomb’s problem is an inferior act’s correlation with a good state that it does not causally promote... In realistic Newcomb problems, a medical condition and a behavioral symptom have a common cause and are correlated although neither causes the other."

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Recommend putting the title in a question format.
